# How to store java application metrics in shared database

Tags: java, database

I have a school project at which i have created a CPU benchmark. The project is made in java in eclipse.

I want every time i run the project the result that the benchmark gives to be written in a online database which only i can see. (it will be something like id: x , CPU_score: y)

The point is that the benchmark will be run by many users and i want to have the results from all of them. Can you recommend me a tool to use for the database?

I have tried to do it using derby but I have encountered some problems and I am not sure that derby is the solution I need

Comment: How do you use Derby ? In Client / Server mode? For storing events like benchmark results a database like [Influx DB](http://influxdb.com/) in conjuction with the [influxdb-java](https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb-java) library looks more appropriate to me.

Comment: I have read about Influx DB now, but my problem is that I don't know how to automatically write in a DB when i run the benchmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For connection use this...

```
private Connection connectToDB() {
        final String dbHost = "url";

        try {
            String dbConnect = "jdbc:informix-sqli://" + dbHost + ":port/databasename";
            Class.forName("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver").newInstance();
            return DriverManager.getConnection(dbConnect, "user", "passwort");

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

To get the Values this...

```
public void getDBContent(Connection conn) {
    final String str = "Select columnname,columnname2,columnname3 from tablename";
    try {
        PreparedStatement sqlStatement = conn.prepareStatement(str.toString());
        ResultSet rs = sqlStatement.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("columnname"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("columnname2"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("columnname3"));

        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I can use the same logic to write in the table instead of getting the values?

Comment: Yes, need to change the String str....

Comment: Search for the Syntax of insertions in SQL. Try Like this "insert Into tablename values( value1,value2 )

Comment: I have created a DB in NetBeans with the following url: jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/benchmark [minion on MINION]. Still I have problems reading from the database because it doesn't do anything. As far as I have seen it doesn't enter the while(rs.next()) loop. I have attached to pastebin the modifications I have made to your code. Did i do a mistake? http://pastebin.com/hNYf3kAN

Comment: You habe to change the String representing the statement. Select * from tablename. And change the rs.getstring Parameter

Answer (score 0):

So on several computers a local program does a benchmark for the local computer, and send it to a central "database"?

1. In a school you could send a message to a special e-mail account. Which might not always be possible,
2. An other option would be to have a PC running full-time a Java EE server like TomCat (free), and send the data there,
3. The third option: your local app could access a central database like MySQL directly. You will have to add remote access to the computer's IP address (GRANT ...), and lower the fire wall for the database port. Be careful with giving write access to the database as SQL can indeed install files on your computer. Run everything under non-admin accounts. Maybe use a non-standard port for the DB, > 1000.

I think 2. is the least frustrating. As you can establish a connection by hand (telnet, browser). Use a local database (like Derby or H2), develop with a stand-alone application.

Comment: So i have to install TomCat and the results when the program is run will be written in my DB? You're right, 2 is the best option. Thank you!

Comment: TomCat is a free JavaEE webserver. On the application side you write the data (say in text form) or as URL parameters to the server `"http://123.45.67.8/benchmark/count?vs=1&a=123.3&b=2323"`. Then a piece of code, a servlet writes it to a local database. The detour making it safer.